# Is it possible to record calls on Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, call-recording

I want to install a **working** call recording application on Galaxy S3, but I have found problems with a few apps.

I have tried [Auto Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appstar.callrecorder) but it doesn't allow me selecting more than *Mic* as audio source. Perhaps I can record only my own voice (I haven't tried further and I obviously haven't bought the full program)

I have previously tried [Call Recorder Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=polis.app.callrecorder.pro) but it only recorded my own voice and not the other party's.

I have read [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skvalex.callrecorder) that most call recorder apps require root (OK for me) and *Requires the kernel with 2-way call recording patch*

### The question is, then

How do I make a call recorder **fully** work on a Galaxy S3 (GT-I9300) with only root for now?
Do I need to flash a custom firmware? Or won't it just work at all?

Comment: All Call Recorder suprisingly did the thing without root or any additional modifications.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use Auto Call Recorder as well (before my S3), and I was highly unsatisfied when it stopped working (when I switched to S3).

Just yesterday I found out this another great app that just works. And seems like much better than ACR: [**Record My Call**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.record.my.call&hl=en) - The solution! No idea how that's even free (even if it does have ads). And, I do have root, but I think this doesn't even need it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. There is no specific need to flash a custom firmware but you can get the job done with a mod which you can flash from recovery preferably clockworkmod. It is always advised to backup data before flashing. Here's the [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1706310) for the mod at XDA. But I'm not sure if two-way call recording is supported in this. You can record the other person's voice but not your voice.

Comment: Pretty useless if it's still one-way (even if *opposite-way*). Question updated for sake of non-ambiguity

Comment: Try [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2091959). This is supposed to work and works well with most users. But make sure that you take the right version which matches with your framework version.

Comment: Thanks for the new link and forgive me if I had no time to test. I will wait for the 4.2 update to roll out to try again. In fact I found this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2173126

Comment: Why wait for the 4.2 update to roll out? There's a leaked 4.2.2 version from Samsung doing the rounds. You can download it from samfirmware.com. You can also try Android Revolution HD or Omega ROM which are of the latest Android version. You may have to wait forever for the update.

Comment: About Revolution and Omega, please understand that I prefer stock by experience. About the leak, I hadn't checked it because I feared it may be unstable for now. Perhaps I could look more into it

Comment: I understand. Revolution is the closest to stock. It's just using the same stock rom and stock kernel with minor feature additions and all useless bloatware removed which make the stock experience even more enjoyable. It actually is very stable. Even though Omega uses the same stock rom, there's too many custom apps and unwanted features. I don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic Call Recorder works great on S3, but it's not free.

If you have rooted device, custom Omega ROM has this feature on board already (just enable in the settings).

Answer (score 0):

[Smart Call Recorder MP3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.glovantech.guniversalrecorder.plus) is a fantastic **free** call recorder. It offers extensive call recording features and it is neatly integrated with Google Drive for automatic backup of your mp3 voice/call recordings.

Comment: What's your affiliation with this app?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can easily record calls on Galaxy S3 device. Install Total Recall auto call recorder application and get your calls automatically recorded. Free app with free trial period of 30 days. Here is the link- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.killermobile.totalrecall

Comment: Looks like an advertisement. What's your affiliation with this app?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please confirm what relationship (if any) you have with this app: it's OK to recommend your own app on this site, provided you're honest about it. Both of your answers on this site have been recommending this app which makes it look like spam.

Answer (score -1):

Galaxy S3 has many variants.

Galaxy S3 GT-I9300 in some countries can record calls well (using any call recorder), in other countries Samsung disabled the call recording feature, so you should root the phone then there are several call recorders can fix the problem.

Galaxy S3 SCH-I535(Verizon), SPH-L710(Sprint), SGH-T999(T-Mobile), SCH-R530C(Cricket), SGH-I747(ATT), SGH-I747M(Rogers) etc can record calls perfectly in two directions without root. Here is the solution: [Galaxy S3 Call Recorder](http://www.boldbeast.com/forum/topic896-galaxy-s3-call-recorder.html). It seems this is the only solution without root, because all other recorders ask you root these phones.

Comment: I own a GT-I9300 and I can record calls with Boldbeast even without root (my phone is rooted, but BB has not ever yet requested me root permissions)

Comment: You didn't read my post carefully. In some countries Samsung doesn't disable the call recording feature of Galaxy S3 (like your country), so almost all recorder record calls well without root. However in some countries Samsung disabled the call recording feature of Galaxy S3, so you should root the phone to fix the recording issue. Boldbeast is one of the several recorders that can fix the issue.